# Two unnexpected errors in generic c++ header file : c2008 # unexpected in macro definition and c1070 mismatched #if/#endif

Tags: c++, header-files

I am getting the following two error messages for the following code

```
#ifndef _SPHERECLASS_H_
#define _SPHERECLASS_H_

#include "DIYRigidBody.h"

//class SphereClass : public DIYRigidBody
//{
//  --info here
//};

#endif
```

c2008 # unexpected in macro definition
and  c1070 mismatched #if/#endif

I have similar code in previous projects and never have I recieved such a problem.

Here are the full errors

Error   4   error C1070: mismatched #if/#endif pair in file 'd:\desktop cleanup\phsics proj\safety 1\tell me its over2\src\sphereclass.h'   d:\desktop cleanup\phsics proj\safety 1\tell me its over2\src\sphereclass.h 15  1   OpenGL Project

Error   1   error C2008: '#' : unexpected in macro definition   d:\desktop cleanup\phsics proj\safety 1\tell me its over2\src\sphereclass.h 2   1   OpenGL Project

//errors that existed b4 i commented out the classes and .cpp info//
Error   3   error C2014: preprocessor command must start as first nonwhite space    d:\desktop cleanup\phsics proj\safety 1\tell me its over2\src\sphereclass.h 14  1   OpenGL Project

//errors that existed b4 i commented out the classes and .cpp info//
Error   2   error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?) d:\desktop cleanup\phsics proj\safety 1\tell me its over2\src\sphereclass.h 3   1   OpenGL Project

note the header files it is including are commented out in a similar fashion leaving only includes and the #if/endif boundaries

Comment: Could you show us your DIYRigidBody.h?

Comment: @Ilya the 2nd last .h file is the DIYRigidBody.h file and Ive changed the name of if accordingly in ther\ project

Comment: @user3580540, try to simplify this example (i.e. reproduce this problem with minimul number of lines). And show us your minimal code.

Comment: @Ilya So I commented out everything with the .cpp file, plus all the class info leaving just the includes. i still recieve error C1070 and C2008. Ill adjust the question accordingly

Comment: @user3580540, great! So, now we have two possibilities: 1) the problem is inside DIYRigidBody.h (try to comment out that `#include` to check it), 2) the problem is in special character in "`_SPHERECLASS_H_`" (we can't see it, because this character was replaced by another one while writing of the question) - try to replace this name by simple "`_MYTEST_`" for checking.

Comment: @Ilya if i comment out the DIYRigidBody.h  i drop the c2008 error. Even if i change the name to mytest the first error remains. I dont know what a special character is, but it seems really strange that i am getting an error for 3 lines of code _> #ifndef _MYTEST_,
#define _MYTEST_,

#endif. Note They are spelt correctly but this writing format loses some of the ___.

Comment: Ok, try to comment out as many lines of file DIYRigidBody.h as it is possible (without loosing of that error). And show us minimal DIYRigidBody.h which provokes that error.

Comment: @Ilya I can comment out the entire DIYRigidBody.h  and i still receive the second error.  The only way to drop the c2008 error is to comment out the #include "DIYRigidBody.h" line itself

Comment: Is it possible, that you have few files DIYRigidBody.h on your computer, and that you edit one of them and include another one? (check you include paths)